# Can't convert string to number type in xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, converters

I have a query which pulls data from an xml file.

The file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CommodityData>
  <Commodity id="Corn">
    <Year value="2019">
     <AcresPlanted value="90005000" />
     <AcresHarvested value="82017000" />
     <AcresProduced value="13900651000" />
     <YieldBuAcre value="169.5" />
    </Year>
    <Year value="2018">
      <AcresPlanted value="89129000" />
      <AcresHarvested value="81740000" />
      <AcresProduced value="14420101000" />
      <YieldBuAcre value="176.4" />
    </Year>
    //...and so on
```

I have a DTO for the data

```
public class GrainDataNass
{
    public string Commodity { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string AcresPlanted { get; set; }
    public string AcresHarvested { get; set; }
    public string AcresProduced { get; set; }
    public string YieldBuAcre { get; set; }
}
```

And I can retrieve all the data with this query

```
 public List<GrainDataNass> GetGrainData(string commodity)
    {
       var query = _doc.Descendants("Commodity")
            .Where(el => commodity == (string) el.Attribute("id"))
            .Descendants("Year").Select(u => new GrainDataNass
            {
                Commodity = commodity,
                Year = u.Attribute("value")?.Value.ToString(),
                AcresPlanted = u.Element("AcresPlanted")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
                AcresHarvested = u.Element("AcresHarvested")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
                AcresProduced = u.Element("AcresProduced")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
                YieldBuAcre = u.Element("YieldBuAcre")?.Attribute("value")?.Value
            }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

The charts I generate with this data need the data fields AcresPlanted, AcresHarvested etc to be numbers. Decimals, as I divide the acreage and production fields by 1,000,000 since they are so large. (Yes I changed the Dto to reflect the type changes)

I tried doing that in the query itself, like this, first only with the yield data since it looks like a decimal already since most values are decimals i.e. 156.4, 160.3 etc

```
{
    Commodity = commodity,
    Year = u.Attribute("value")?.Value,
    AcresPlanted = u.Element("AcresPlanted")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
    AcresHarvested = u.Element("AcresHarvested")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
    AcresProduced = u.Element("AcresProduced")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
    YieldBuAcre = Convert.ToDecimal(u.Element("YieldBuAcre")?.Attribute("value")?.Value)
            }).ToList();
```

I also tried converting the other 3 values to doubles or longs so I could divide them by 1,000,000 but all the conversion attempts produced exceptions

> "Input string not in correct format"

Can I not convert the data within the query? Do I have to convert it after I've pulled it from the xml file?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToDecimal(string)` performs a culture-specific conversion which might fail for you if the decimal separator of your cultture is not '.'.

Option 1: Use `Convert.ToDecimal(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Option 2: XAttribute has conversion facilities built in as cast operators which do the conversion according to the XML rules, e.g. `(decimal?)attribute`. With this second option (which I like more), your code would be:

```
_doc.Descendants("Commodity")
        .Where(el => commodity == (string) el.Attribute("id"))
        .Descendants("Year").Select(u => new GrainDataNass
        {
            Year = u.Attribute("value")?.Value.ToString(),
            AcresPlanted = u.Element("AcresPlanted")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
            AcresHarvested = u.Element("AcresHarvested")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
            AcresProduced = u.Element("AcresProduced")?.Attribute("value")?.Value,
            YieldBuAcre = (decimal?)u.Element("YieldBuAcre")?.Attribute("value")
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Gutter...tried both those methods, each produces the same exception

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem in the input data? I tested with the two Year elements of your sample and it worked fine.

Comment: Gutter...Well, that made me look at the file, yes I had two empty sections at the end of the xml section which might have been the issue...And after removing them, it works now. As an aside, the (decimal?) way of doing this doesn't work, VS sees it as an code error

Comment: Did you declare the property as `decimal` or as `decimal?` - in the former case and if YieldBuAcre is always present, replace the cast by `(decimal)`.

Comment: Gutter...yes, changed property type to decimal? and used (decimal?) in the query. And I tried both decimal and decimal?